# in SQL Server does LEFT() convert nvarchars to int?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a bunch of alphanumeric codes stored as Nvarchar. I want to take all the codes that begin with a 1 and append .00001 onto the end of them. I tried this code

```
,CASE 
     WHEN left(1,[CASE_CODE]) = '1'
     THEN concat([CASE_CODE],'.00001')
      ELSE [CASE_CODE]
      END as [CASE_CODE]
```

But I get this error message

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'PVC00595' to data type int.

Is the LEFT function converting to int for some reason?

Comment: I think your problem is using `left(1,[CASE_CODE])` instead of `left([CASE_CODE], 1)`

Comment: haha always something super simple thanks

Comment: So 1.5 would be come 1.5.00001  ???

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `left` takes a character expression followed by an integer expression. Your error is coming from `left(1,[CASE_CODE])` trying to convert `CASE_CODE` into an integer expression (since it is the second argument).

You want `left([CASE_CODE], 1)` (reversed arguments) instead.